# pyqgis create layer from a list of points

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, python-3

I am working with pyqgis in QGIS3 and i want to create a point layer from an intersection beetween a point and a polygon layer. I can identify wich points intersects my polygon layer but i can't use them in a new layer. I think i have to store the result in a new point layer with a list, but it not seems to be the good argument.

How can i "populate" a point layer with a list like ?

```
[<QgsGeometry: Point (505555.56033052341081202 6341490.30133426282554865)>, <QgsGeometry: Point (505555.56033052341081202 6341490.30133426282554865)>, <QgsGeometry: Point (505555.56033052341081202 6341490.30133426282554865)>, <QgsGeometry: Point (505555.56033052341081202 6341490.30133426282554865)>]
```

Here is my code

```
# Points
myPoints = "C:\pyqgis\mypoints.shp"
layerPoints = QgsVectorLayer(myPoints, '', 'ogr')

# Polygon
myPolygon = "C:\pyqgis\mypolygon.shp"
layerPolygon = QgsVectorLayer(myPolygon, '', 'ogr')

# Intersection
featureList = []
for i in layerPoints.getFeatures():
        for p in layerPolygon.getFeatures():
            if i.geometry().intersects(p.geometry()):
                featureList.append(geom.asWkt())                

# Create layer with result
intersection = QgsFeature()
intersection.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(featureList))

# Add it to the map
result = iface.addVectorLayer(intersection, "result", "ogr")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a memory layer as in following code:

```
registry = QgsProject.instance()

# Points
myPoints = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/mypoints.shp"
layerPoints = QgsVectorLayer(myPoints, 'points', 'ogr')
registry.addMapLayer(layerPoints)

# Polygon
myPolygon = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/mypolygon.shp"
layerPolygon = QgsVectorLayer(myPolygon, 'polygon', 'ogr')
registry.addMapLayer(layerPolygon)

# Intersection
featureList = []
for i in layerPoints.getFeatures():
    for p in layerPolygon.getFeatures():
        if i.geometry().intersects(p.geometry()):
            featureList.append(i.geometry())                

epsg = layerPoints.crs().postgisSrid()

# Create layer with result
uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'intersection_points',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(featureList)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(featureList[i])

prov.addFeatures(feats)

registry.addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running it in Python Console of QGIS 3, I got (with my path's layers) following result:

[image]

Intersection points are visualized in red; as expected.